# Onsubmit window.location is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, window.location

I have a **textbox** and a **search button**.

`Onclicking` **search button** the `window.location` is working.

But on pressing enter key `window.location` is not working.

I have read that submit works when enter key is pressed but why here on pressing enter key window.location is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
<form  id="form">
<input id="bar"
style="height:26px;  left:29%; top:270px; position:absolute;   
border:1px solid #CCC;
font:20px arial,sans-serif; 
background-color:transparent; z-index:6; outline:none; 
width:500px;"
spellcheck="true";
onfocus="";
type="text" value=""  title="Search" autocomplete="on" maxlength="2048" />
</form>

<input id="searchbutton"
style="height:30px; top:330px; position:absolute; left:33%; background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
background-color:#f8f8f8;
border:1px solid #c6c6c6;
box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
color:#333;
border-radius:2px;"

type="button" value="Google Search"/>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#searchbutton").click(function() {

        var q;
        q = $("#bar").val();
        window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + q;
    });

    $('#form').submit(function() {

        var q;
        q = $("#bar").val();
        window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + q;
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: why not change text input type to submit?

Comment: window.location.href =

Comment: @A.Wolff:why would anyone press enter key on button?
I am talking about textbox here.

Comment: window.location.href is also not working on pressing enter key on textbox

Comment: also, would be easier to add an action pointing to google url and also add method = get ,right?

Comment: @A.Wolff: you can test it form can be submitted by pressing enter key.

Comment: @ArunSharma ya, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cancel the form submit.  Try changing the code to as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#searchbutton").click(function(){

    var q;
    q=$("#bar").val();
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+q;
    });

    $('#form').submit(function(){

    var q;
    q=$("#bar").val();
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+q;
    event.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

When you hit the enter key, the form will initiate the submit event.  By default, the page will submit to itself if you don't specify a destination (in the action attribute).  Since you are not cancelling the submit event, even though you were trying to redirect the user to a different page, the page submit will take presidence and completes the submit; therefore, the page never redirects to google.com.

Also, as @Quentin mentioned in his comment, it best practice to change:

```
$("#searchbutton").click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#searchbutton").click(function(event){
```

since the event object is handled differently across different browsers.

Comment: Thanks alot..
But can you explain what event.preventDefault(); did here?
It would help me.

Comment: You haven't changed the function to accept an `event` argument

Comment: thank you for explaining .i like to learn things rather than just copying the codes.